# How to restore PostgreSQL database schema dump into different database (Eg: Apache Derby,H2)?

Tags: postgresql, derby, h2, in-memory-database

I am writing a JUnit test which needs an in-memory database.

We are using PostgreSQL database and it can't be used as in-memory database.

Could you provide any suggestions on how to restore a PostgreSQL schema dump into different in-memory database (eg: Apache Derby, H2)?

Comment: Don't use a different DBMS for your tests. That makes the tests essentially meaningless.

Comment: The JUnit test wants to test the liquibase update/rollback scripts on postgreSQL  database . Is there any other way ?